# Get last record only in PHP array

Tags: php

I have an array serving multiple purpose, sometimes I use it for displaying all records, sometimes I use it for displaying the first record, sometimes I use it for displaying the last record.

For displaying all records, I can use

```
<?php foreach($array['products'] as $product) { ?>
  <li>Name: <?php echo $product['name']; ?>'/></li>
<?php } ?>
```

For displaying the first record, I can use

```
<?php $product=reset($array['products']); ?>
  <li>Name: <?php echo $product['name']; ?>'/></li>
```

For displaying the last record, what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [*end*](https://www.php.net/end),

```
<?php $product=end($array['products']); ?>
  <li>Name: <?php echo $product['name']; ?>'/></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $product[count($product)]['Name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [end()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) will do this. It moves the pointer to the end, and returns the last element.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$products=array_reverse($products);

<?php $product=reset($array['products']); ?>
  <li>Name: <?php echo $product['name']; ?>'/></li>
```

Comment: better way is given by Rikesh.

Answer (score 0):

Use end, this will forward your array to the end and return the pointer.

`echo end($products);`